# Objects not being displayed in Django Admin when Foreign key is Null

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters, django-modeladmin

I have a Model "Item" that has a field "req_item", that's a nullable foreign key. Everything seems to working fine, but when the "req_item" field is null, the object is not displayed in django admin altogether. Here's the image for reference:
[image]

All the "req_item" filed values are null in DB at the moment, so none of the objects are displayed. If I assign a valid req_item value to an object in the DB, then only that object is displayed. How can I fix this issue.
Here's my admin.py

Comment: please add `admin.py`

Comment: Please find relevant admin.py here: https://pastebin.pl/view/a8763e33

Comment: Can you check if the same issue is present when you use default `ModelAdmin`, please?

Comment: No, this issue is not present if I don't use any filters.

Comment: Nice, I would suggest to remove part by part elements of `ItemFilter` and see when the problem show up